# How to use executorService to make http call in J2EE application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, executorservice

I want to get an idea of using ManagedExecutorService in stateless bean. Basically i am trying to send a http call in a separate thread inside my j2EE application. executorService send this request and wait for x number of seconds to receive response, if no response comes in specified seconds OR get exeception then do another try(X times) and then finally give a feedback that either https service call successfully done or failed. Here is my code

```
@SuppressWarnings("EjbEnvironmentInspection")
@Resource
ManagedExecutorService executorService;

public static final long RETRY_DELAY = 3000;
public static final int MAX_RETRIES = 3;
 executorService.execute(() -> {
        int retry = 0;
        Collection<Info> responseInfo = null;

        while (responseInfo == null && retry++ < MAX_RETRIES) {
            try {
                responseInfo = httpsService.requestAccessInfo(requestInfo);
                Thread.sleep(RETRY_DELAY);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Error while receiving response retry attempt {}", retry);
            }
        }

        boolean status = filledLockAccessInfo==null ? false : true;

        event.fire(regularMessage(status,GENERATION_RESULT);

    });
```

Can someone tell me is it a right way to do this OR not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to forcibly sleep (`Thread.sleep(RETRY_DELAY);`). What you need is an asynchronous invocation of the service that can support timeout.

The following two methods use the completable future API's timeout and error handling to implement that.

The following use recursion to retry the given number of times:

```
private static Collection<Info> callService(int retryCount) {

    try {
        CompletableFuture<Collection<Info>> f =  invoke();
        return f.get(RETRY_DELAY, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }catch(TimeoutException te) {
        if(retryCount > 0) {
            return callService(retryCount - 1);
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Fatally failed!!");
        }
    } catch(Exception ee) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unexpectedly failed", ee);
    }
}
```

Note that the `executorService` object is passed in the second argument of `supplyAsync`

```
private static CompletableFuture<Collection<Info>> invoke() {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        //call
        return httpsService.requestAccessInfo(requestInfo);;
    }, executorService);
}
```

With that, you can simply  call it with the number of retries:

```
Collection<Info> responseInfo = callService(MAX_RETRIES);
```

To make the above call run asynchronously, you can replace the preceding statement with:

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> callService(MAX_RETRIES))
            .thenAccept(res -> System.out.println("Result: " + res));
```

This will make the call in the background. Later, you can check how it completed:

```
f.isCompletedExceptionally() //will tell whether it completed with an exception.
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion let me try this. One question, rather than i depend on any TimeoutException in callService to make a another retry, Is it possible to do something like if service not respond after x second then i make another try ?

Comment: If you see the call `f.get(RETRY_DELAY, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)`, the parameters are essentially the timeout config, meaning if connection service doesn't respond or can't be connected to in that time period. If it times out, the `get` method will raise a timeout exception. This is the only control flow I know is available in the API for catching timeouts. You can look into connection and read timeout value change for your http client, but that would be specific to the HTTP client that you're using.

Comment: I have tested your solution but it seems to be that when i do Collection<Info> responseInfo = callService(MAX_RETRIES); This mean caller of this method should have to wait until executorService done it work and then i have to trigger event for response. If you see my code i want that calling http and result is going under separate thread. So how i can do this while using these 2 suggested method ?

Comment: Yes, in the above answer, calling `callService(MAX_RETRIES)` will block and will make the caller wait, because it's explicitly calling `.get`. Will add an example that makes the entire thing take a callback and run asynchronously.

Comment: Updated with an example that makes the entire call async

Comment: I am sorry i think we missing something here, i tried to use CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> callService(MAX_RETRIES))
            .thenAccept(res -> {System.out.println("Result: " + res); //rest event.fire() stuff}); call of this method is now going async way but i am not receiving any result in thenAccept after end of 3 times retry to http stuff

Comment: Did you try to check with `f.isCompletedExceptionally()` as suggested? Completable future has other methods for chaining and customizing behavior of callbacks, depending on what you want to do...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169262/discussion-between-user565-and-ernest-kiwele).

Comment: I have added a code into a chat which seems to be not calling CompletableFuture